Spring security: how to hide or bypass the "login with oauth2" page with a single oauth client, when using oauth2Login
I'm migrating to the latest spring security. My current project uses the deprecated EnableOAuth2Sso configuration with the following config. Whenever I go to the /login page of my app, it will automatically redirect to the URLs specified below (the SSO site).
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=http://localhost:8081/user

With the latest spring security 6, using the oauth2Login, it seems like now spring wants me to define a list of client registrations. I have something like this
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-id=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-secret=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/myclient
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myclient.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myclient.token-uri=http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myclient.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8081/user
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myclient.userNameAttribute=name

It seems like I can set multiple oauth clients in my app. However, the annoying thing is that if I go to the /login URL, I'm seeing a login page provided by spring with my defined oauth client as the single option. My question is that how can I get this to the previous behavior, to not show this page and just redirect me to the SSO site for login?


Easy one: you have the frontend redirect the user to the URL pointed by the link standing for the login option you are interested in (probably tools in your case) instead of the login screen (something like http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/tools).

So there is no way of defining a singular client in the new spring security? It had to be a list of clients?

Client registrations were a list since at least Spring Security 5. The default generated login page should do an auto redirection when there is only one client registration with authorization_code, but this breaks if, for instance, you have http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.loginPage("...") in your conf. So, without seeing your conf, it's hard to tell what's happening.
